# Alternative of executing same sql query again with different parameters

Tags: sql

I need to do the following :

```
select table1.abc from table1 where col1 = ? and col2 = ?
```

The problem here is i need to get data from this table for 3 sets of (col1, col2).
I don't want to execute the same query 3 for different parameters.

Also i want to have the result set of the executed query containing 3 columns of data (1 for each set of col1,col2).

Let me know if any further details are reqd.

Comment: What database are you using? The answer could change based on the platform. :)

Comment: Is there only one row in the result of your query? And what is the datatype of `table1.abc`?

Comment: @lc yes there is only 1 row per set of col1,col2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use subselects if there's only one result for your query:

```
select (select table1.abc from table1 where col1 = ? and col2 = ?),
    (select table1.abc from table1 where col1 = ? and col2 = ?),
    (select table1.abc from table1 where col1 = ? and col2 = ?)
from table1
limit 1
```

Comment: Could you comment on efficiency of this over the other? Are there any plus points?

Answer (score 1):

You can use OR clause with 3 sets having different parameter set

```
select table1.abc from table1 where (col1 = ? and col2 = ?)
OR (col1 = ? and col2 = ?) OR (col1 = ? and col2 = ?)
```

Comment: this would return three rows..but i need only 1 row in result set but 3 columns in that row